# Meaning of "greater than or equal to" in a proof - set or support?

Tags: self-learning, terminology, inequality

You are asked to "Offer a proof of the following":  Suppose that $X$ is a random variable, $X \in \mathbb{R}$.  If $7X^3+5X \ge X^2+8$, then $X \ge 0$

**Proof 1**:  $X(7X^2+5) \ge (X^2+8)$.  $X \ne 0$ because $(0)(5) \ge 8$ is not true.  $X$ cannot be less than zero because (negative)(positive) >= (positive)  is also not true.  Therefore, $X \gt 0$.  Therefore, $X \ge 0$

**Proof 2**:  $7X^3 - X^2 + 5X - 8 \ge 0$, solving for the real roots, we find $X \ge 0.8593196$.  Therefore, $X\ge 0$

My question is on the last step of either proof. When asked to perform a proof, are you only saying that I have proven a subset, $X>0$  or $X \ge 0.8593196$, therefore the superset is true, that $X \ge 0$, **OR** are you making a statement about the domain of $X$, that zero is an allowed value of $X$ which makes the last conclusion false so you cannot prove $X\ge0$.

Is there an authoritative reference for this?  Perhaps a manual on proofs?

**Note**:  This is not a homework problem, I have tried to distill the question to help elucidate the point.

**Edit**

Perhaps a different way of asking the question is whether a proof like this is asking if there exists at least one $X$ that makes both statements true, or if we are to prove that the support of $X$ is on $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: "A implies B" does not imply that "B implies A".  The former is what you are being asked to prove; the truth of the latter, which seems to be what you are worrying about after the OR, is not what you are being asked to prove and is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

There's an even more elegant way, without a single calculation - proving by contradiction:

Let $7X^3+5X\ge X^2+8$ and assume $X<0$. The term $X^2+8$ is bound to be positive. As $X$ is negative, $X^3$ is also negative and thus the term $7X^3+5X$ is promised to be negative. That is, if we assume $X<0$ we reach a contradiction because $7X^3+5X< X^2+8$. We can conclude that if $7X^3+5X\ge X^2+8$ then $X\ge0$. $\blacksquare$

---

Generally speaking, when we need to prove that A leads to B ("if A then B"), there are 3 major types of mathematical proofs:

1. [Proving by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction), where we assume that the opposite (if A then not B) and then prove that if (not B) then A doesn't stand. That's my proof up there.
2. [Proving by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction), kinda self explanatory.
3. [Proving by construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_proof), where we go step by step (if A then C, if A,C then D, if A,C,D then E...   until we get to prove B).

There are, of course, [many other types of proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_proof), but these are the main 3 types AFAMKG.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I think my proof #1 was a proof by contradiction, perhaps not stated in the same way.  I think your point might be that, if you are asked to prove X>=0, then just prove X cannot be less than zero and be done.  Don't worry about the fact that X cannot equal zero.  Is that right?